# System of non-homegeneous linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I need to find a relation between $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ in order the system with the following augmented matrix has at least one non-trivial solution. I have tried both the Gaussian and Gauss-Jordan elimination methods, but I think it is gets too complicated in the end. Thanks in advance.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{c|c}
      A&b\\
    \end{array}
\right]  =
 \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      2&3&-1&4&a\\
      3&1&-1&0&b\\
      0&2&1&1&c\\
      -1&0&-1&3&d
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Comment: Why do you expect a simple solution? There are 16 numbers crawling around in that matrix, it's fortunate that the solution is as simple as it is. Also you should post the relationship you found so we can see if it's correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaussian elimination produces
$$ \left[ \matrix{1 & 3/2 & -1/2 & 2 & | & a/2\cr
                  0 & 1 & -1/7 & 12/7 & | & 3a/7 -2b/7\cr
                  0 &  0   & 1 & -17/9 & | & -2a/3 + 4b/9 +7c/9 \cr
                  0 &  0   &  0 &    0 & | & -a+b+c+d\cr}\right]$$

so the condition for a solution is $-a+b+c+d=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you can swap rows if it's **convenient**, not only if it's **necessary**.  Doing this, the row-reduction becomes very simple:
$$\pmatrix{-1&0&-1&3&|&d\cr 0&2&1&1&|&c\cr 0&3&-3&10&|&a+2d\cr
    0&1&-4&9&|&b+3d\cr}
  \sim\pmatrix{-1&0&-1&3&|&d\cr 0&1&-4&9&|&b+3d\cr 0&0&9&-17&|&c-2b-6d\cr
    0&0&9&-17&|&a-3b-7d}$$
and I'm sure you can finish it from here.

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed a useful method when you are stuck.

Comment: You're welcome!  The point is that it's always helpful if you can get the first nonzero entry in each row to be $1$ or $-1$.